# slurm sbatch standard IO redirection

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, slurm

I need to run a parallel program that needs to read from standard io. How could I pass a file to it in slurm sbatch? I tried the -input command but didn't work. here is my sbatch script

```
    #!/bin/sh

    #SBATCH -p main
    #SBATCH --nodes=1
    #SBATCH --ntasks=1
    #SBATCH --time 0-23:59:59
    #SBATCH --reservation=VR0188
    #SBATCH --input /vlsci/VR****/phillis/input.txt


    # Run info and srun job launch

    echo 'start work--------------------'

    srun helloworld
```

and here is my test code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <omp.h>

     main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

     int nthreads, tid;

     #pragma omp parallel private(tid)
       {
       /* Obtain and print thread id */
       tid = omp_get_thread_num();
       printf("Hello World from thread = %d\n", tid);

       }  /* All threads join master thread and terminate */

       int a;
       scanf("%d", &a);
       printf("file input read as %d\n",a);
     }
```

this program can be successfully submitted and run, but the scanf result is always:

```
     file input read as 0
```

Comment: did you try either `srun helloworld < input.txt` or `cat input.txt | srun helloworld`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--input` option in sbatch will transfer the file to the standard in put of the submission script, not that of your program. You have three courses of action:

1. move the `--input` argument to the `srun` call: `srun --input /vlsci/VR****/phillis/input.txt helloworld`
2. transfer the standard input of the submission script to that of `srun`, which will in turn transfer it to `helloworld`: `cat | srun helloworld`
3. ignore the `--input` parameter and use redirection explicitly: `srun helloworld < /vlsci/VR****/phillis/input.txt`

Comment: I tried all of them but get the same error result: "slurmstepd: error: execve(): helloworld: Permission denied"

Comment: never mind, it works; just need to put the scanf outside of the parallel block; thank you very much!